# How to change the position of the figure?

Tags: floats

I got the following figure which the display isn't visually satisfactory. Figure follows:
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Lift coefficient\label{Lift coefficient}}%
[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.39]{Figures/plotMatlabEvaluation/GormontsCl}}
\hspace{\fill} 
\subcaptionbox{Drag coefficient\label{Drag coefficient}}
[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.39]{Figures/plotMatlabEvaluation/GormontsCd}}

\caption[$C_{L}$ and $C_{D}$ Gormonts Model]{$C_{L}$ and $C_{D}$ static values and using the  Gormonts dynamic stall Model}
\label{fig:RotorGeometry}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

It seems that my code makes a gap between the subfigures. Can I change somehow the length of this?

Figure:

[image]

Comment: I take it from the vertical red line in the right hand side graph that you do *not* want the figure to protrude into the right-hand margin. However, the right hand side graph also seems to suggest that it's OK to have the figure protrude into the *left-hand margin* (whereas that wasn't the case in the left-hand graph, labelled "current display"). Is this the intended impression, or do you simply want the entire figure fit into the text block, i.e., not protrude into either margin?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing a scaling-related option to `\includegraphics`, you could simply repeat the `width=0.4\linewidth` option. (Incidentally, I would assume that there's nothing special about `0.4\linewidth`. If that's correct, you may want to experiment with `0.47\linewidth` in order to avoid having such a big visual gap between the two subfigures.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}  % for \subscaptionbox macro
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to demonstrate width of text block
\begin{figure}[h]
%% \centering % not needed
\subcaptionbox{Lift coefficient\label{Lift coefficient}}%
[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{Figures/plotMatlabEvaluation/GormontsCl}}
\hspace{\fill} 
\subcaptionbox{Drag coefficient\label{Drag coefficient}}
[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{Figures/plotMatlabEvaluation/GormontsCd}}

\caption[$C_{L}$ and $C_{D}$ Gormonts Model]{$C_{L}$ and $C_{D}$ static values and using the  Gormonts dynamic stall Model}
\label{fig:RotorGeometry}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer.Unfortunatelly it didnt output the desired result.It seems that my code always produce a specific gap between the subfigures which makes this result.(No exp in latex to find out why).

Comment: @MpizosDimitris - What is the desired result?

Comment: The subfigures became too small.By changing the width to higher values the right subplot moved again to the 'area' that i dont want :/ Maybe is that gap between the figures that i mention in the edited post.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris - In what sense do the subfigures become too small? The main point of the method proposed in my answer is that you can *choose* the width of the subfigures: if `0.4\linewidth` is not wide enough, select `0.47\linewidth` instead. Note that `0.47\linewidth` needs to occur four times if you make this change. Are you maybe keeping one `scale=...` option?

Comment: I dont use scale.I change the value of linewidth but the right figure goes further of the 'text limit',similar to my code display.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris - If you're not using `scale=...` after all, please consider updating your example to show what you *are* doing. Without this information, it's going to be impossible for me to offer further advice.